# How to calculate the Jacobian matrix?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, jacobian

I want to calculate the Jacobian matrix of $F_a$ for $x = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$. $F_a$ is the transformation defined below. 

$$F_a(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta) := (a(\theta)r\cos\theta, a(\theta)r\sin\theta) \ \ \ (\theta \in [0, 2\pi))$$

$a(\theta)$ is differentiable. 

The book I am now reading suggests that the answer is below.
$${\rm d}F_a(x) =
\begin{pmatrix}
a(\theta)\cos\theta & a'(\theta)\cos\theta - a(\theta)\sin\theta \\\ 
a(\theta)\sin\theta & a'(\theta)\sin\theta - a(\theta)\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}$$
However, I have no idea why I can get this answer. Could you show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F = (f_1, f_2, f_3)$. Then the rows of the jacobian are
$$(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial r}, \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial \theta}).$$

Calculate them, and you should get the transpose of what you wrote. Maybe, the book uses a different convention.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have already calculated as you say. But, $r$ remained. Thus, it might be a wrong way to get the answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. This is definitely not the wrong way to get the answer, as it the definition of the jacobian. Seems like a typo in the book.